# Building a Bidimensional Array in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, multidimensional-array, plsql

I am trying to make a matrix to display on 7 lines the days of the week and on each line the total of people hired in the years 93,94,95,96,97, 98 and 99 based on a table  that has their hire date as for example 02-May-94.

Basically I want to display on console something like:

[image: On console.]

The problem is that I can not find a way to create such a structure on the `dbms_output.put_line`, as I don't want to create a table for this, I just want to link the results together.

Any ideas would be really welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dbms_output is not really a formatting tool.

Comment: @OldProgrammer quite true, thus my migraine but our barely out of University professor thinks otherwise.

Comment: You could use a PIVOT - http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended doing it manually.

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dia          93   94   95   96   97   98   99  ');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_dom );

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_lun);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_mar);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_mie);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_jue);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_vie);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(var_sab);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------');